# Has anyone managed to get Watir using IE on Ruby 1.9.1 working?

Tags: ruby, winapi, watir

I'm new to ruby and am having trouble getting a simple watir script to work with IE on ruby v1.9.1. I can get it to work with ruby v1.8.6

Has anyone managed to use watir with Ruby v1.9.1 ?

This is the script i'm using

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'http://www.ruby-lang.org/'
```

Below are details of my attempts with both versions where i have tried on both 32 bit Windows XP SP3 and 32 bit Windows 7. IE 8.0 is the default browser in both cases, i must use IE as this is what my customers require.
All installs were got from http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

## v1.8.6

- ruby -v gives me ruby 1.8.6 (2010-02-04 patchlevel 398) [i386-mingw32]
- RUBYOPT environment variable is set to 'rubygems'
- Path environment variable is set to include 'c:\ruby186\bin'  - no other version is in the path
- Installed watir with gem install watir
- gem list gives me
  - activesupport (2.3.8)
  - builder (2.1.2)
  - commonwatir (1.6.5)
  - firewatir (1.6.5)
  - hoe (2.6.1)
  - json_pure (1.4.3)
  - nokogiri (1.4.2.1 x86-mingw32)
  - rake (0.8.7)
  - rubyforge (2.0.4)
  - s4t-utils (1.0.4)
  - user-choices (1.1.6.1)
  - watir (1.6.5)
  - win32-api (1.4.6 x86-mingw32)
  - win32-process (0.6.2)
  - windows-api (0.4.0)
  - windows-pr (1.0.9)
  - xml-simple (1.0.12)

```
SUCCESS
```

## v1.9.1

- ruby -v gives me ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-mingw32]

  RUBYOPT environment variable is set to 'rubygems'

  Path environment variable is set to include 'c:\ruby191\bin' - no other version is in the path

  Installed watir with gem install watir

  gem list gives me

  - activesupport (2.3.8)
  - builder (2.1.2)
  - commonwatir (1.6.5)
  - firewatir (1.6.5)
  - hoe (2.6.1)
  - json_pure (1.4.3)
  - nokogiri (1.4.2.1 x86-mingw32)
  - rake (0.8.7)
  - rubyforge (2.0.4)
  - s4t-utils (1.0.4)
  - user-choices (1.1.6.1)
  - watir (1.6.5)
  - win32-api (1.4.6 x86-mingw32)
  - win32-process (0.6.2)
  - windows-api (0.4.0)
  - windows-pr (1.0.9)
  - xml-simple (1.0.12)

```
FAILURE : simplegoto.rb:58:in `<main>': undefined method `goto' for #<Watir::IE:0x16eaca0> (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks in advance
Pat

Comment: The last time I have tried, Watir worked only with Ruby 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

The version of Watir you are using only works with 1.8.6, as far as I know.

Vapir (updated fork of watir - see http://vapir.org ) works with all recent versions of ruby.

EDIT:

Or update to a newer version of watir (which may not have been an option in 07/2010 but is surely the case now in 2012.  both watir 2.0.x and watir 3.0 (in RC status at the time I update this answer) support more current versions (e.g. 1.9.2) of Ruby

Answer (score 1):

To allow Watir (and FireWatir) to run on ruby 1.9.2
install devkit and follow procedures listed here : [Ruby Installer at GitHub](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)

```
gem uninstall win32-api
gem install win32-api --platform=ruby
```